# Pattern which will transform a given expression

Tags: pattern-matching, rule

Find the `Pattern` which when applied to this expression

```
expr = {a^2, a^b, x^4, (x - 1)^2};
```

yields this result:

```
{2 a, a^(-1 + b) b, 4 x^3, 2 (-1 + x)}
```

Comment: `expr /. a_^b_ :> b a^(b - 1)`?

Comment: .. or `D[#, Cases[{First@#}, _Symbol, Infinity]] & /@ expr`?

Answer (score 2):

Applying a pattern to a list of expressions to transform the expressions doesn't make much sense. Perhaps there is a language issue here and you mean to ask what pure function you could map over your list to do the transformation. If so, kglr's answer in a comment is what you want.

Here is a slightly simplified version:

```
D[#, FirstCase[#, _Symbol, #, ∞]] & /@ {a^2, a^b, x^4, (x - 1)^2}
```

> `{2 a, a^(-1 + b) b, 4 x^3, 2 (-1 + x)}`